# How much data can be loaded per cycle from the GDDR5?

Tags: gpu, memory-bandwidth

nVidia GTX980 has 224GB/s bandwidth and 7Gbps memory clock. Its bus width is 256bit.

Can we calculate how much max/min data can be loaded in parallel from the GDDR5?

Can I get the answer from dividing 224GB/s by 7Gbps?

Comment: This is a good question. You may also want to ask it here: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've already got the answer. 224GB/s equals to 7Gbps x 256bit as

```
224==7*256/8
```

The bus width is the limit.